# Is 方 read かた or ほう here?

Tags: kanji, readings

Example sentences:

1. 外の方が家の中より暖かそうです。
2. たいふうは西の方に去った。

ty!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both cases, it is read as ホウ ([the on'yomi](http://kakijun.jp/page/0458200.html)).

One simple and helpful thing to realize is that the ほう reading means "direction" but the かた reading refers to either a person or way of doing something.

If you think about it, the first sentence is

> 外の方が家の中より暖かそうです。

"It seems  warmer outside than inside the house."

> たいふうは西の方に去った。

"The typhoon went to the West"

Both are directional.

Comment: Ah got it, thanks Kierkegaard! I thought that was the case for the first sentence, but I was dumb enough to consult trusty google translate and it told me it was read as kata :/ ... I really should have learnt my lesson by now.

Comment: Yes, the main lesson is -- don't trust Google translate for Japanese translation or rather ["Googleは日本の翻訳に翻訳信用していません"](https://translate.google.com/#en/ja/don't%20trust%20Google%20translate%20for%20Japanese%20translation) to prove my point.

Comment: Maybe trust something like this: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/comparison before we try Google Translate again. It's really not reliable at all. f>~<')