# 方【ほう】 or 方【かた】?

Tags: readings, reading-comprehension, multiple-readings

方【ほう】 or 方【かた】?

In this post [Is 方 read かた or ほう here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30397/31150) I read that 方【ほう】 means "direction" and 方【かた】 means "a person/way of doing something."

What about in this sentence?

> だけど、血【ち】の通【かよ】った人間【にんげん】として見【み】た方【ほう】がはるかにおもしろい([source](https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASP9T3QQ7P9JPLZB01L.html?iref=comtop_Topic_03))
> *But seeing flesh-and-blood human beings is far more interesting.*

I do not see in this sentence how 方 can mean either "direction," "person," or "manner." If anything, wouldn't it be "a way/type of looking" and thus 方【かた】?

Comment: This is a comparison, so it's the ほう reading.

Comment: “A way/type of looking” would be [見方]{みかた}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's read ほう because it's part of the basic pattern of comparison, `～方が + predicate`. It *could* be understood as an extension of "this side/direction (of seeing ...)", but IMO it can be just memorized as a pattern of comparison. The act of "seeing" itself is not a person.

Also note that 血の通った人間**として**見る is not "to see flesh-and-blood humans" but "to see them as flesh-and-blood humans".